# Mysql query, more specifically with Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I think I've hit my peak on mysql query knowledge. I can't seem to generate, what I suspect, is a complex query. Here's a little background on my setup and then to the problem. I have 3 tables. For the sake of brevity I'll only list the relevant columns.

```
customers
- id

customer_fields
- id
- name

customer_datas
- id
- customer_id
- customer_field_id
- value
```

This setup allows for a client to create any number of fields that are attached to a customer. The customer_datas holds the value for the customers field and is linked to a data item. For example:

```
customer (1 record)
- id: 1

customer_fields (2 records)
- id: 1
- name: firstname

- id: 2
- name: lastname

customer_datas (2 records)
- id: 1
- customer_id: 1
- customer_field_id: 1
- value: John

- id: 2
- customer_id: 1
- customer_field_id: 2
- value: Doe
```

Here's the problem. I'm able to pull the data for each customer and even a list of customers. What I'm not able to do is order the data by a column, in this case, it'd have to be some sort of pseudo column.

Here's an example. I can't just run an ORDER BY firstname because I don't have that column on my customers table. It's all dynamic, so firstname is a field the client sets up and is in the customer_fields table. I'd like to be able to order by whatever customer_field the client sets up but I fear my knowledge of mysql queries is a bit limited. I'm also not sure Laravel eloquent is capable of something like this. If not, I can just go the raw route.

I've never done anything quite this dynamic, so I'm willing to accept the possibility that my setup is all wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even just pointing me in the right direction.

Also, apologies if this has already been covered somewhere. I felt this was quite a specific case and I couldn't find any information regarding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who posted. I've come up with the correct solution due in part to all your input:

I made a scope on the customers model

```
public function scopeOrderByCustomField($q, $field, $direction)
{

    $q->select('customers.*')
      ->join('customer_datas as ca', 'ca.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
      ->join('customer_fields as cf', 'cf.id', '=', 'ca.customer_field_id')
      ->where('cf.name', $field)
      ->groupBy('customers.id')
      ->orderBy('ca.value', $direction);

}
```

I had to add the select because the id on the customers table was being overwritten by the join and the groupBy needed to be added, well, to group the customers to a single entity :)

Comment: You don't need to group by `customers.id`, since there can only be one "firstname" per customer. If that is not the case, `ORDER BY ca.value` wouldn't  make much sense. Also note that you can not sort this way correctly using numeric values.

Comment: My example was pretty basic. In my actual workflow I do have fields that have multiple values like phone, fax, etc... Without the groupBy I was running into issues. In my list, I do only need to present the primary value for each of those fields that have multiple values.

Thanks for making me aware of the sort by numeric value issue. I suppose once that issue comes up I'll deal with it then, heh

Answer (score 0):

I feel you on your confusion. Sometimes Eloquent isn't the right way to go about the query because Eloquent will perform multiple queries to fetch the data. This can lead to confusion as to how to properly construct your query.

Ultimately, and 99% of the time for larger, more complex queries, you're going to want to use the Fluent Query Builder, instead.

Here's an example using a custom `local Query Scope` on your `Customer` model that leverages the `Fluent Query Builder`.

```
public function scopeOrderByCustomField($field, $direction) {
    Customer::join('customer_datas as ca', 'ca.customer_id', '=', 'customer.id')
        ->join('customer_fields as cf', 'cf.id', '=', 'ca.customer_field_id')
        ->where(cf.name, $field)
        ->orderBy('ca.value', $direction)
}
```

Which should ultimately give you the `Customer` list sorted by the `$field` you pass in and going the `$direction` you provided.

In application, it would look something like this:

```
$customers = Customer::orderByCustomField('first_name', 'ASC')->get();
```

**Note** that it's important to call `->get()` yourself as the `queryScope` returns an instance of the `Query Builder` and therefore no results are fetched until calling `->get()` or `->first()` etc.

Comment: Ah, I will give this a try, thank you. The function should be scopeOrderByCustomField though, correct?

Comment: Nice... I fear the problem is still the same though. My customer_fields table doesn't have a column lastname or firstname. So I'd have to do orderBy('cf.name', 'asc') but that isn't what I need :( I need to order by the lastname for instance asc so I'd get John Doe, John Hancock, etc... There is no column for me to order by though because it's dynamically created as a row in the customer_fields table.

Comment: The idea looks good, even though I'm not sure if `orderBy()` works within a scope. However - the query is probably wrong. You need somewhere `where(cf.name, $field)` and `orderBy(ca.value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it overly complex. All that data can go into one table, the customers table.

```
customers
  - id
  - firstname
  - lastname
```

Then maybe if you had like an addresses table, break the data up.

```
addresses
 - id
 - customer_id
 - street
 - city
 - zip
 - etc.....
```

Then you would setup a relation between the customer and his/her address based on the customer_id, etc... You can read more on relationships in laravel docs. [laravel relationships][1].
That would make sense for a new table.

> There is no reason to have a table with firstname just to point to
>   another table with the actual "firstname".

---

UPDATE

---

Ok, then make another table

```
  customer_data
  - id
  - customer_id
  - field_name
  - field_data
```

You can dynamically add and remove as many fields as you'd like from that table. Still, keep it simple.

**UPDATE**

```
$data = DB::table('customer_datas')
    ->where('field_name', 'first_name')
    ->orderBy('field_data', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: The whole point is to make the fields dynamic so the client can add and remove columns themselves and also to allow for the deleting of a column that has data attached to it but still keep the data. Maybe I didn't explain correctly, my apologies for that.

Comment: @Patrick No worries, I just think you can do what your trying to do easier then your thinking. Checkout my update.

Comment: @Patrick it's basically what you were trying to do before but with one table. There is no reason to have the fields name in one table pointing to another table with the data.

Comment: I saw your update and thank you for your input. I feel like we're getting a little away from the original question though which is how to perform a query to order by the field name. With your update, you didn't provide a way of ordering by the field name. I need to order by firstname, asc or desc. Your solution doesn't offer a way to do that. Also, field_name could just be an id to the fields table where I can store a lot more information relevant to that field, which I'm doing, and just have a relationship.

Comment: @Patrick of course you have to set up the relationships and stuff, customers hasMany customer_data and I would set the reverse. Does that make sense?